# Running rubygem (Middleman) on Azure

Tags: ruby, azure, middleman

I have just signed up a trial account on Azure to see if it is a viable platform for me in long-term.

Using a webworker role with a variety of CMD and startup scripts, I managed to get ruby working on the cloud - a simple "Hello world" message!

However, I am unable to get [Middleman](https://github.com/middleman/middleman) started automatically and cannot see anything in the logs to indicate what's wrong. I just get a "Page unavailable" when I navigate to the app.

Maybe I am using the Azure in the wrong way. Any ideas? Also is there anything on Azure to allow me to debug issues via RDC or similar?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you wand to server actual pages by middleman? What is your intention of using Azure + middleman?

Answer (score 1):

If you get Ruby running in your worker role, you definitely can run Middleman together with it. There could so many issue i.e. specific content missing in Worker Role, proper network settings etc and you can troubleshoot most of such issues by RDP to your Windows Azure Worker Role. You can enable RDP access as described below with your Role and Once you are in your VM, you can easily figure out what could be problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx

If you are creating package directly from Windows Azure SDK tool (without using VS2010) then you may need to do some extra efforts to include RDP specific settings in your deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did deploy directly from VS2010 and I was able to RDP but was not able to see any of these files that I had deployed earlier. Is there a reason why I shouldn't install Ruby, etc. within RDP and leave at that?

Comment: You must not install/configure anything on Azure VM over RDP because VM does not persist any data so in case of update/reimage/vm-recycle, all of your configuration will be gone. (This is because you are using Azure VM in PaaS Model, the new Azure VM (preview) does persist data but it is IaaS model)

Comment: So within the VM, where abouts I need to look, e.g. logs on why it is not working? Sorry I am quite a newbie when it comes to Azure hosting :o)

Answer (score 0):

Middleman is meant to generate static websites, which you can then serve directly with any sort of server. There's no reason to have Ruby or any special server where your site is deployed - just copy over the static files!